# Remove Tab from Fragment Tabs Pager example

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments, fragment, android-compatibility

I'm trying to use the Fragment Tabs Pager example:
[API 4+ Support Demos/Fragment Tabs Pager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html) and add the abillity to delete a tab, because I need to be able to add and remove tabs.

I've tried:

```
public void removeTab(int position) {
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().removeView(mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(position));
}
```

but this does not work.

I've also tried removing all the tabs and re-adding them with the tabSpec which I stored when initially adding the tabs:

```
    public void removeTab(int position) {
      mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
      mTabHost.clearAllTabs();

      ArrayList<TabInfo> mNewTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

      mTabs.remove(position);
      int len = mTabs.size();
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          TabInfo info = new TabInfo(mTabs.get(i).tag, mTabs.get(i).clss, mTabs.get(i).args, mTabs.get(i).tabSpec);
          mNewTabs.add(info);
          }
      mTabs.clear();
      mViewPager.removeAllViews();
      mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(position).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        addTab(mNewTabs.get(i).tabSpec, mNewTabs.get(i).clss, mNewTabs.get(i).args);
      }
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

This removes the tab, but when the tab had been instantiated, then when adding a new tab the original fragment is displayed.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem of being able to remove and add tabs or replace the fragment within a tab.

Comment: Hi, had the same problem. You have to say, that this bevavier just appears, if you are remove a tab between two other tabs. Remove tabs at the end works like a charm.